# Snowflake 'Transient' table shows retention period of 90 days

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I created a transient schema "Employee_Schema" in which I created a normal table "Employee"

```
create table Employee(Id Int, Name String, Salary Double)
data_retention_time_in_days=90;
```

Now because the schema was transient, the table also became transient as well.
Problem is the retention period of 90 days got attached to it where as Snowflake documentation shows transient tables cannot have retention period more than 1 day.

To validate the same I create a normal schema within which I created a transient table with retention period of 90 days which threw an error.

[image: Below image shows transient table having 90 days retention period]

[image: Below image shows same issue verified from information schema of the DB]

[image: Below image shows transient table created in normal schema having retention period>1 day throwing an error]

Comment: I ran your "CREATE TABLE Employee..." statement within a transient schema and it errored: SQL compilation error: Exceeds maximum allowable retention time (1). I think you need to re-check what you actually did as your description of events doesn't seem to be possible. Can you re-create the behaviour?

Comment: I was able to replicate this issue myself.  I would suggest entering a Support ticket with the details.  The table shows as transient, but with 90 days of retention in the `SHOW TABLES` command, but not sure whether that is purely a metadata or display issue vs. whether you are actually seeing 90 days of time-travel in your table.

Comment: @NickW
Try following steps
1. Create transient schema
2. Create a normal table within that schema with 90 days retention
3. Because the schema is transient the table is transient as well.
4. But the retention period is 90 days!!

Comment: @MikeWalton
I thought the same thing as well, so it checked the same thing in "information_schema" to verify the retention period, there as well I'm able to see 90 days of retention. I have attached screenshot of the same.

Comment: Very strange - I cannot replicate this behaviour. If I'm in a transient schema it will not let me create a table with a retention period > 1. I've tried in both permanent and transient DBs. I ran this as ACCOUNTADMIN - are you running it with a role that has any specific permissions?

Comment: @NickW
is your snowflake account Enterprise or above, if not you cannot create a table with 90 days of retention.

Comment: Doh :) I'm on a Standard account

Comment: @OmkarRahane The question is are you able to actually see changes older than 1 day in that table?  If not, then this is likely just a metadata issue.  Regardless, I recommend opening a Support ticket with Snowflake.